# Converting netmask number to 32 bit in golang

Tags: go, network-programming, ip, subnet, netmask

I am trying to get the IP address and subnet mask by

```
ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
for _, iface := range ifaces{
        localip, _ = iface.Addrs()
}
```

However, I am looking forward to get the subnet as something like `255.255.255.0` rather than `/24`. How can I get that? If there are no modules that can do this, what is the logic to do this as a program?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://golang.org/pkg/net/#IPMask.Size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowed from some stackoverflow post itself, using logical operators.

```
mask = (0xFFFFFFFF << (32 - 24)) & 0xFFFFFFFF; //24 is the netmask
var dmask uint64
dmask = 32
localmask := make([]uint64, 0, 4)
for i := 1; i <= 4; i++{
    tmp := mask >> (dmask - 8) & 0xFF
    localmask = append(localmask, tmp)
    dmask -= 8
}

fmt.Println(localmask)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
func main() {
    ifaces, err := net.Interfaces()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, iface := range ifaces {
        addrs, _ := iface.Addrs()
        for _, addr := range addrs {
            cidr := addr.String()
            mask, err := mask(cidr)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("extracting mask failed:", err)
            }
            i, err := mtoi(mask)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("creating uint16 from mask failed:", err)
            }
            fmt.Printf("CIDR: %s\tMask: %d\n", cidr, i)
        }
    }
}

// Extracts IP mask from CIDR address.
func mask(cidr string) (net.IPMask, error) {
    _, ip, err := net.ParseCIDR(cidr)
    return ip.Mask, err
}

// Converts IP mask to 16 bit unsigned integer.
func mtoi(mask net.IPMask) (uint16, error) {
    var i uint16
    buf := bytes.NewReader(mask)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &i)
    return i, err
}
```

Comment: Could you kindly explain this as an inline comment?

Comment: I just extracted two functions to make the code cleaner. Notice that `net.Mask` is defined as `type IPMask []byte` so it may be more useful in this form.

Answer (score 4):

Converting netmask to type "IP" before printing does the trick:

```
func mask_print(ipnet *net.IPNet){
  fmt.Println("%v", net.IP(ipnet.Mask))      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a function like:

```
func parseMask(ipaddr string) (mask string, err error) {
    removeExtra := regexp.MustCompile("^(.*[\\/])")
    asd := ipaddr[len(ipaddr)-3:]
    findSubnet := removeExtra.ReplaceAll([]byte(asd), []byte(""))
    subnet, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(findSubnet), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return "", errors.New("Parse Mask: Error parsing mask")
    }
    var buff bytes.Buffer
    for i := 0; i < int(subnet); i++ {
        buff.WriteString("1")
    }
    for i := subnet; i < 32; i++ {
        buff.WriteString("0")
    }
    masker := buff.String()
    a, _ := strconv.ParseUint(masker[:8], 2, 64)
    b, _ := strconv.ParseUint(masker[8:16], 2, 64)
    c, _ := strconv.ParseUint(masker[16:24], 2, 64)
    d, _ := strconv.ParseUint(masker[24:32], 2, 64)
    resultMask := fmt.Sprintf("%v.%v.%v.%v", a, b, c, d)
    return resultMask, nil
}
```

and then call it:

```
func main() {
    ifaces, _ := net.Interfaces()
    for _, iface := range ifaces {
        localip, _ := iface.Addrs()
        for _, ip := range localip {
            done, _ := parseMask(ip.String())
            log.Println(done) // 255.255.255.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following function that i wrote works for ipv4:

```
func NetMaskToString(mask int) (netmaskstring string) {
var binarystring string

for ii := 1; ii <= mask; ii++ {
    binarystring = binarystring + "1"
}
for ii := 1; ii <= (32 - mask); ii++ {
    binarystring = binarystring + "0"
}
oct1 := binarystring[0:8]
oct2 := binarystring[8:16]
oct3 := binarystring[16:24]
oct4 := binarystring[24:]

ii1, _ := strconv.ParseInt(oct1, 2, 64)
ii2, _ := strconv.ParseInt(oct2, 2, 64)
ii3, _ := strconv.ParseInt(oct3, 2, 64)
ii4, _ := strconv.ParseInt(oct4, 2, 64)
netmaskstring = strconv.Itoa(int(ii1)) + "." + strconv.Itoa(int(ii2)) + "." + strconv.Itoa(int(ii3)) + "." + strconv.Itoa(int(ii4))
return
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options.  You can do a type assertion to *net.IPNet from which you can grab the mask, as shown.  Or you can parse the given CIDR address.  The parse can be done with the [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) as shown, or by using net.ParseCIDR to get a *net.IPNet from which you can grab the mask.  Disclaimer: I am the project manager for IPAddress.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go/ipaddr"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ifaces, _ := net.Interfaces()
    var localips []net.Addr
    for _, iface := range ifaces {
        addrs, _ := iface.Addrs()
        localips = append(localips, addrs...)
    }
    for _, localip := range localips {
        fmt.Println("for the IP", localip)

        // one way is to type assert
        ipnet := localip.(*net.IPNet)
        maskBytes := net.IP(ipnet.Mask)
        fmt.Println("\tcasted mask is", maskBytes)

        // another way is to parse the string
        cidrStr := localip.String()
        maskAddr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(cidrStr).GetAddress().
            GetNetworkMask() // add .GetNetIP() for net.IP
        fmt.Println("\tparsed mask is", maskAddr)
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
for the IP 127.0.0.1/8
        casted mask is 255.0.0.0
        parsed mask is 255.0.0.0
for the IP ::1/128
        casted mask is ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
        parsed mask is ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff
for the IP fe80::1/64
        casted mask is ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
        parsed mask is ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
for the IP fe80::10ba:1591:f2b5:cfc7/64
        casted mask is ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
        parsed mask is ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::
for the IP 192.168.1.165/24
        casted mask is 255.255.255.0
        parsed mask is 255.255.255.0
for the IP 9.211.112.150/19
        casted mask is 255.255.224.0
        parsed mask is 255.255.224.0
```